# How do I create multiple objects in Java?

Tags: java

Couldn't be simpler. In Android Studio I have a class called `Dog` and I simply wish to create numerous `Dog` objects. I can do it as shown below but I guess there's a much less tiresome way. Is there?

```
final Dog buster = new Dog();
final Dog rover = new Dog();
final Dog fido = new Dog();
// and more
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: You can use a loop, but then the dogs would end up in an array and addressed by number.

Comment: That's a basic question on the language. At this point you should just read a tutorial

Comment: Hi hex, Yes. Surely there's a way of somehow listing all the dogs in braces or something and then instantiating them in one go. e.g. (buster, rover, fido etc)

Comment: I have, Dici, but haven't found the answer. If it's that basic, just tell me how I should do it.

Comment: There're many ways to accomplish this. What's the desired outcome?

Comment: The desired outcome is simply to simplify the statements and reduce their number. I mean, what if there were 1000 dogs to create! Do we really need 1000 lines of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be an amusing way to do it:

```
public enum DogName {
    buster, rover, fido
}

....
EnumMap<DogName,Dog> dogs = new EnumMap<DogName,Dog>();
for (DogName name : DogName.values()) {
    dogs.put(name, new Dog());
}
```

This compiles:

```
import java.util.EnumMap;

class Dog {
    public enum DogName {
        buster, rover, fido
    }

    private static final EnumMap<DogName,Dog> dogs = new EnumMap<>(DogName.class);
    static {
        for (DogName name : DogName.values()) {
            dogs.put(name, new Dog());
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `EnumMap` if you are going to do it that way.

Comment: [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html). Not that you necessarily need to use `EnumMap` to have a `Map<DogName,Dog>`, but `EnumMap` is intended for it.

Comment: Just tried it, Tibrogargan and it doesn't compile, gives 4 errors. Sorry.

Comment: @John of York I wouldn't expect it to compile any more than yours compiles for me.  You will need to put the code inside a function, probably need to import EnumMap.  I'm assuming you have a Dog class already.  The "...." is commonly accepted to mean "insert your stuff here".

Comment: Can't believe it's the accepted answer. It's not even simpler than the snippet in the question, no more generic (or very slightly) =(